# How can I own a string through reference if its lifetime is static?

Tags: rust

In Rust I would like to give a name to a class, and this class owns this name.

Sometimes the name is passed by an `String`. For this case I can just simply move the ownership.

But sometimes this name is given by a static string(`&str`).
For this case I want to refer to that string, rather than making a `String` from it.

My question is: how can I declare this name field in my class?
What type should it be?

---

Some updates/background on the requirements:

- The name will be immutable.
- The reason why I want to distinguish a `String` and a `&str` is that I want to reduce the dynamic allocation to the minimum.

Comment: Maybe [`Cow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/enum.Cow.html)? Feel free to write an answer about this, if it helps...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to declare the name member as an enum that can either contain a `String` or an `&'static str`:

```
enum Name {
    Static(&'static str),
    Owned(String),
}

struct Class {
    name: Name,
    // ...
}
```

The class can then provide appropriate constructors (there will have to be two) and a `get_name()` method for accessing the name as string slice:

```
impl Class {
    pub fn new_from_str(name: &'static str) -> Class {
        Class { name: Name::Static(name) }
    }
    pub fn new_from_owned(name: String) -> Class {
        Class { name: Name::Owned(name) }
    }

    pub fn get_name(&self) -> &str {
        match self.name {
            Name::Owned(ref s) => s.as_str(),
            Name::Static(s) => s,
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let c1 = Class::new_from_str("foo");
    let c2 = Class::new_from_owned("foo".to_string());
    println!("{} {}", c1.get_name(), c2.get_name());
}
```

The other option is to use the [`Cow` type](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/enum.Cow.html) provided by the standard library for this purpose:

```
use std::borrow::Cow;

struct Class {
    name: Cow<'static, str>,
}
```

Since `Cow` implements the `Into` trait, the constructor can now be written as a single generic function:

```
pub fn new<T>(name: T) -> Class
    where T: Into<Cow<'static, str>> {
    Class { name: name.into() }
}
```

`Cow` also implements the `Deref` trait, allowing `get_name()` to be written as:

```
pub fn get_name(&self) -> &str {
    return &self.name;
}
```

In both cases the `name` member will equal the size of the larger variant plus the space taken by the discriminator. As `String` is the larger type here, and it takes up three pointer sizes (the string contents is allocated separately and doesn't count), `Name` will take four pointer sizes in total. In case of explicit `enum`, the member can be made smaller still by boxing the string:

```
enum Name {
    Static(&'static str),
    Owned(Box<String>),
}
```

This will cut down the size of `Name` to three pointer sizes, of which one slot is used for the discriminator and the remaining two for the string slice. The downside is that it requires an additional allocation and indirection for the owned-string case - but it might still pay off if the majority of your class names come from static string slices.

Comment: Could you also give more information on the size of `enum Name`?

Comment: @TheBusyTypist As always in Rust, the size of an enum equals the size of its largest member, plus the size of the discriminator. In this case, the larger member would be `String`, which amounts to three pointer-sized machine words. (Here size refers to the size of the struct, which does *not* include the contents.) Due to alignment, the whole `Name` enum amounts to the size of four pointers.

Comment: @TheBusyTypist I've updated the answer to include the option of boxing the name, which cuts down the size to three pointers. Given that `&str` is a slice represented with pointer and `usize`, I don't think you can make it smaller than that, except using `unsafe` trickery with pointer masking.

Comment: That's a great example of using `Cow`. I was just about to edit my code but saw you used `Into` as well :)

Comment: @squiguy Yeah, I've just about reinvented `Cow`. I would have deleted the `enum` code, except it might be interesting for learning about `enum`s (which `Cow` uses internally anyway) and, more importantly, it allows the additional boxing size optimization.

Comment: If you really care about the one word you could save by boxing the `String`, maybe rather use [`into_boxed_str()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.into_boxed_str). It avoids additional allocation and indirection. You just can't edit the string contents anymore, which might be fine... Also: this conversion can be reversed with [`into_string()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.into_string)

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt That's actually a very nice improvement on that approach, thanks. It's a shame that the answer has grown so long already that I'm wary of adding new stuff in.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do to allow for a mix of types is use the [`Into`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.Into.html) trait. This is versatile in that it makes sure a safe conversion happens between the types.

A `str` slice can be converted "into" an owned `String` as such.

Some test code to demonstrate it:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Test {
    name: String,
}

impl Test {
    pub fn new<T: Into<String>>(t: T) -> Test {
        Test { name: t.into() }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let t = Test::new("a");
    println!("{:?}", t);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I thought we still dynamically allocate a copy of `"a"` for `name`, which I think is not necessary. Is it possible to eliminate  this copy?

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that this was a requirement. It sounds like `Cow` is your best bet after all.